# How do I disable voting in Trello?

Tags: trello

I'm currently trying out [Trello](https://trello.com/) by using it to manage a personal to-do list. Since I'm not collaborating with anybody else, the voting feature is unnecessary. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disable the voting feature on a specific board:

1. Click the icon to the left of the board's name to open its menu.
2. Select *Preferences* from the menu.
3. Set *Feature: Voting* to "Disabled" and your're done!

[image]

Votes that were added prior to voting being disabled will still be displayed.